# Any way to cast type in pandas dataframe query?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, types, casting

Assume i have a dataframe with 3 columns, all in float type, name it DT1. 
Now if i want to create another dataframe from DT1 by query DT1, say the second one is called DT2.

```
DT2 = DT1.query(‘(column1/column2) == (column3/column2)’)
```

This will work only if two sides of the equation are exactly match. 
What if I only want to compare the integer results of two side?

Like:

```
DT2 = DT1.query(‘(column1/column2).astype(int) == (column3/column2)’).astype(int)
```

The example above won't work, any solution?

PS:

```
DT2 = DT1.loc(‘(DT1[column1]/DT1[column2]).astype(int) == (DT1[column3[/DT1[column2]).astype(int)’)
```

will work. I am curious if it can work through query.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

assuming you have the following DF:

```
In [125]: df
Out[125]:
   col1  col2   col3
0  2.11   1.1  2.101
1  1.00   1.0  3.000
2  4.40   2.2  4.900
```

you can use `DataFrame.query(..., engine='python')`:

```
In [132]: df.query("col1 // col2 == col3 // col2", engine='python')
Out[132]:
   col1  col2   col3
0  2.11   1.1  2.101
2  4.40   2.2  4.900
```

or `DataFrame.eval(..., engine='python')`:

```
In [126]: df[df.eval("col1 // col2 == col3 // col2", engine='python')]
Out[126]:
   col1  col2   col3
0  2.11   1.1  2.101
2  4.40   2.2  4.900
```

Check:

```
In [131]: ((df.col1 / df.col2).astype(int) == (df.col3 / df.col2).astype(int))
Out[131]:
0     True
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: nope, it says TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for //

Comment: Nice solution with integer division and the engine parameter usage :-) +1

Comment: @Windtalker, glad i could help :)